# Java date class comparing two Strings of dates

Tags: java, string, date, time, string-comparison

I have the following problem with the date class. I want to compare the string that comes with the toString() method of date class, with the string that a user gives as date and time. When comparing the two strings, equals() always returns false even if i copy/paste the date and time! Is there any way to compare the date and time string successfully only with the Date class? Thanks very much!!

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SystemTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        String timeNow = new String((new Date()).toString());
        System.out.println(timeNow);
        System.out.println("Give date and time: ");
        String time = new String(input.next());

        if(time.equals(timeNow)){
            System.out.println("same");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not same..");
        }
    }

}
```

**EDITED**

I had to use the date class to compare dates the right way!

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has yet explained *why* you shouldn't compare dates as strings, I'll do so.  A "date" is an abstract idea representing an instant in time, and a Java `Date` (or more recently the classes in `java.time.*`) is a class that implements that abstract concept.  A string (i.e. from `toString`) is just one way to express the abstract concept of an instant in time, and as you know different localities have different ways of expressing dates/times.

If you want to compare the abstract "instants in time", then you should parse the user's input into a class representing that instant and compare instants. This allows you to verify that the user's input represents a valid instant instead of returning the wrong result just because the user made a simple typo.

Then there's the whole matter of time zones, but that's a huge topic that's out of scope here.  Date manipulation is an extremely deep and complex topic, and is very hard to get right.

Comment: You can provide a logic that would parse any string to a Date as long as String actually holds a valid date. Here is a link on the article about this topic: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles

Comment: I understood what you said. But is there any other way to compare the day,month,year from user with the ones in date? timeNow.getYear() or getMonth() doesnt seem to work.

Comment: _"doesn't seem to work"_ isn't enough information to help you.  What does the user-entered date look like?  Please [edit] your question to show the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method **compareTo** in the Date class.

```
timeNow.compareTo(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compare Dates and not Strings. You will need to parse the String that user gives you into Date and then compare it with another date. Class Date has methods `before(Date)`, `after(Date)` and `compareTo(Date)` Please see Javadoc API for class Date: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html